# Convergence of various forms of Prospect Theory?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, utility, expected-utility, risk-aversion

I'm not a mathematician but it seems that my problem is a rather technical than an economic one, but i hope this is still the right audience.

My problem is the following: I want to analyse the effects of using Cumulative Prospect Theory (CPT for brevity) on portfolio choice problems and have already implemented a portfolio optimizer using various forms of CPT (which i took from the literature). Basically, i used some form of continuous outcome CPT as well as discrete outcome forms plus another form that applies outcomes generated from a binomial model:

My first CPT (abbreviated as CPT(1)) has the form:
$$U(\Delta{W})=\int_{-\infty}^{0}v(\Delta{W^{+}})dw^{+}(1-P(\Delta{W}))-\int_{0}^{\infty}v(\Delta{W^{-}})dw^{-}(P(\Delta{W}))$$
where $dw()$ denotes the derivative of a decision weighting function, $P(\Delta{W})$ denoting a cumulative probability density function and $v(\Delta{W)}$ is a stepwise power function $\Delta{W}^\alpha$ (where $\alpha<1$) with $\Delta{W}$ being the change of wealth given a reference point.

My second CPT (lets call this one CPT(2) for convenience) has the form:
$$U(\Delta{W})=\sum_{i=-m}^{-1}v(\Delta{W_i})[w^{-}(\frac{i+m+1}{n+m})-w^{-}(\frac{i+m}{n+m})]+\sum_{i=1}^{n}v(\Delta{W_i})[w^{+}(\frac{n-i+1}{n+m})-w^{+}(\frac{n-i}{n+m})]$$
where the $n+m$ observed changes in wealth $\Delta{W}$ are sorted ascending with $-m$ being the largest loss up and $+n$ being the largest gain. Each change in wealth is observed with equal probability $p(\Delta{W_i})=(\frac{1}{n+m})$.

My third CPT (denoted as CPT(3)) is similar to CPT(2) except for the fact that the change of wealth is determined by an upside return $R_{u}>1$ and an equivalent $R_{D}<1$ and where changes in wealth $\Delta{W}=R_{U}^{t-j+1}R_{D}^{j-1}-1$ and the probabilities are those from the associated binomial distribution.

My question is the following:
If i assume the changes in wealth of CPT(1) and CPT(2) are normally distributed with $\Delta{W}\sim{NV(\mu;\sigma^2)}$, i suspected that for a very lange number of observations, form CPT(2) converges to CPT(1). However, i run several simulations in Excel VBA and my CPT(2) got nowhere near CPT(1):

[image]

Herein Lambda and Gamma are parameters for $v(\Delta{W^{+/-}})$ and for the decision weighting function (they don't affect the difference between the two CPT forms as much as $\alpha$).

If i set all parameters to one i get what i expected:
[image]

Note: I used Gauss-Laguerre to evaluate the numerical integral of CPT(1).
My suspicion is that the reason why CPT(2) is larger than CPT(1) has something to do with $\alpha$ and i guess some sort of numerical approximation error in the integral or some sort of difference due to Jensens Inequality is driving my results?

My second question is: Under what circumstances does CPT(3) converge to CPT(1) and how does the cumulative probability function $P(\Delta{W})$ need to be modified (if at all)?

Please let me know if anything is unclear or whether you have further questions.

I appreciate any hints and help/ideas from you.
Thanks a lot

Thomas